# Cannot run python from conda env

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, mamba, termux-linux

I installed mamba (can be seen as conda) in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The Ubuntu is run in the Termux app in my Android mobil phone.

After I created and activated a new environment `mamba create -n general python=3.9 && mamba activate general`, and run `python`, I got `zsh: command not found: python`. If I run `pip`, I got `zsh: /home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/bin/python3.9: no such file or directory`

I checked the environment path `echo $PATH` and found no problem: `/home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/bin:/home/ssy/mambaforge/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`.

However, the python in `/home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/bin` is red in terminal. Like the figure below. I think this should be problem. But I don't know how to fix it.

[image: ls -lh in /home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/bin]

I post the display below, if you can't see the figure. The red part displayed in my terminal is start with [red] in the codes below.

```
-rwxrwxr-x 2 ssy ssy 147K Aug 12 23:43 opj_decompress
-rwxrwxr-x 2 ssy ssy 130K Aug 12 23:43 opj_dump
-rwxrwxr-x 2 ssy ssy  19K Sep 11 16:38 pal2rgb
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ssy ssy  255 Oct  3 07:34 pip
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ssy ssy  255 Oct  3 07:34 pip3
-rwxrwxr-x 2 ssy ssy  14K Sep 16 18:26 png-fix-itxt
-rwxrwxr-x 2 ssy ssy  57K Sep 16 18:26 pngfix
-rwxrwxr-x 2 ssy ssy  19K Sep 11 16:38 ppm2tiff
-rwxrwxr-x 2 ssy ssy  25K Feb  6  2021 psicc
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy   18 Oct  3 07:34 pydoc -> pydoc3.9
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy   18 Oct  3 07:34 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.9
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy  170 Oct  3 07:34 pydoc3.9 -> /home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/.condatmp/.l2s.b4b598da-901e-4a51-92f8-f365d232b1870001
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy  170 Oct  3 07:39 pyftmerge -> /home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/.condatmp/.l2s.ef6942e7-20e1-4cd4-ab45-3d4698eb9d050001
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy  170 Oct  3 07:39 pyftsubset -> /home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/.condatmp/.l2s.27f3e951-238c-4e0d-ab8b-0327731af9450001
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy   18 Oct  3 07:34 python -> python3.9
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy   18 Oct  3 07:34 python3 -> python3.9
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy   18 Oct  3 07:34 python3-config -> python3.9-config
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy  170 Oct  3 07:34 python3.9 -> /home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/.condatmp/.l2s.8500ff74-3bb0-449b-86b4-b7f4072f5f520001
[red]lrwxrwxrwx 1 ssy ssy  170 Oct  3 07:34 python3.9-config -> /home/ssy/mambaforge/envs/general/.condatmp/.l2s.8a47f509-b22b-4961-b99c-1bfd67e7c6c30001
-rwxrwxr-x 2 ssy ssy  23K Sep 11 16:38 raw2tiff
```

Comment: Additional information: 1, The directories pointed to by the red part of the picture don't exist, but I don't know where they run to; 2, I got the same result doing the same operation in AidLux app.

Comment: Did installation finish correctly? That looks like what might be left around if Conda didn't finish replacing links. Maybe try creating the environment again. There could also be some weirdness with the emulator implementation. Since it looks like a filesystem issue, maybe try disabling Conda's linking options by setting it to copy-only (`conda config --set always_copy true`).

Comment: Installation doesn't raise an exception. Reinstallation also doesn't work. But ```conda config --set always_copy true``` works! You saved me! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda is designed to minimize redundant files by using hardlinking with a fallback to softlinking when working across volumes. One possibility is that the terminal emulation doesn’t support some of these operations. One can configure Conda not to use them by setting it to copy-only mode.

```bash
conda config --set always_copy true
```

Note that this means Conda will no longer be disk space efficient. You might want to spend time identifying what operations are not working in the emulation. That is, try using the `ln` function in the shell to create hard and soft links to see if they work. That would be helpful information to pass along to the emulator developers so they can work on supporting it.